# NSNotificationCenter in custom UIView controller error after dismiss and present again

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a view controller with some views and a custom `uiview`. When I touch the screen with my finger I draw a line thanks to the custom uiview.

To do that I send `location.x` and `location.y` through Notification Center to my custom `uiview` like that

```
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
userInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[userInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location.x] forKey:@"x"];
[userInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location.y] forKey:@"y"];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"addLine" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
```

**And in my custom uiview I receive all in this way:**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(addLine:) name:@"addLine" object:nil];
NSDictionary* userInfo = notification.userInfo;
float x = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"x"] floatValue];
float y = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"y"] floatValue];
p = CGPointMake(x,y);
```

**and it works well!!! But just the first time!!!**

**The problem is**
If I dismiss the main viewcontroller where my custom uiview is initialized and I come back (to play again for example) this error appears

> [__NSCFType addLine:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x1454dec0
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType addLine:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1454dec0'

It seems that the observer doesn't work again after a dismiss...can you help me?

thanks

Comment: Have you implemented addLine: method?

Comment: Seems that when you called [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"addLine" object:self userInfo:userInfo]; compiler doesn't get addLine:

Answer (score 3):

You have probably forgot to remove the oberver in the dealloc

```
- (void)dealloc {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

}
```

Comment: No problem, I also suggest you to use a delegate pattern and not a notification for this kind of problems

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this way.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
//....YOUR_CODE....
//Add Observer
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(addLine:) name:@"addLine" object:nil];
}

//Implement method for the notification
-(void)addLine:(NSNotification *)notification
{
NSDictionary* userInfo = notification.userInfo;
float x = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"x"] floatValue];
float y = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"y"] floatValue];
p = CGPointMake(x,y);
}

//and implement dealloc or viewDidDisappear or viewDidUnload method to remove observer.
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:@"addLine" object:nil];    
}

//In Your Custom view or view controller, post notification as below..
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"addLine" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
```

Comment: If you add the VC as an observer in `-viewDidLoad` you should definitely *not* remove it in `-viewDidDisappear` as recommended here. Doing so would result in your notifications stopping if you navigated away and back to the controller quickly. Remove the observer in `-viewDidUnload` or `-dealloc` as shown in this example

Answer (score 0):

In your postnotification method inside object you are passing self but while adding observer, inside that object you are passing nil. So modified the below method like that:-

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
selector:@selector(addLine:) name:@"addLine" object:self];
```